# What's wrong with this sql? invalid reference to FROM-clause entry

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT
    ( * ) AS "count" 
FROM
    "crowd_exports"
    LEFT JOIN "cdp"."public"."crowds" AS "crowds_1" ON "crowds_1"."id" = "crowd_exports"."crowd"
    LEFT JOIN "crowds_components" ON "crowds_components"."crowd_id" = "crowds"."id"
    LEFT JOIN "components_common_upload_crowds" ON "crowds_components"."component_id" = "components_common_upload_crowds"."id" 
    AND "crowds_components"."component_type" = 'components_common_upload_crowds' 
WHERE
    "components_common_upload_crowds"."export_original" = TRUE;
```

The above query when executed returns following error.

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "crowds"
> LINE 6: ...s_components" ON "crowds_components"."crowd_id" = "crowds"."...
> ^
> HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "crowds_1".
> , Time: 0.001000s

Comment: Please tag only one database

Comment: `LEFT JOIN "crowds_components" ON "crowds_components"."crowd_id" = "crowds"."id"` There is no a table aliased as `crouds` in the data source.

Answer (score 4):

> What's wrong with this sql?

Well, there is hardly anything *right*. Starting with "this sql", which should really be "this query".

Why the double-quotes? Why the `LEFT JOIN`? `SELECT distinct count(*)` is complete nonsense. `"cdp"."public"."crowds"` is an illegal database-qualification. The `WHERE` condition contradicts `LEFT JOIN`. The alias is wrong: remove it, or use it. Why qualify the table `crowds`, but not the other tables?